# How to stop the filter after certain count(java 8 - lambda expression)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

**`list.stream().filter((a,b) -> a < count);`**

I need to have two arguments as shown above in filter of stream, how to do that. In above code **a** is model class **b** is int field which counts the number of **c's** and it should stop filtering when it reaches count
Please help me to write this.

I want to skip the filtering when b (increment after each filter) reaches the count.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops filtering when it reaches count"?  Can you update your question with an equivalent `for` loop for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Misha, it means it should stop filtering when it reaches that count

Comment: Do you want to find the first element `a` in your list for which `a.b < count`?

Comment: int i = 0;
  list.stream().filter(c -> {
    i++;
    if(i < count) {
     return false;
    }
    return true;
   }); something like this

Comment: So you want to skip the first `count` number of elements from the stream?  Use `.skip(count)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer

**Solution** is to  use **`list.stream().limit(count)`**

Answer (score 2):

`filter()` takes a `Predicate`, which if you look at its single abstract method (SAM), you can see that the function calls for a single parameter.  That said, to do what you are asking, you only need one parameter, which is the current type of the stream at that stage.  Your expression should look like

```
.filter(a -> a.b < count)
```

Comment: It's important to note that a `true` response allows the object to continue down the pipeline, while `false` discards the object.  So when you say "stops filtering" you mean you want the stream to stop when you have reached the count, or do you want to skip until you reach the count?

Comment: stream to stop when it  reaches the count

Comment: Your answer below doesn't match what you said here--if you want the stream to go until it reaches the count, instead of skip() use limit().  skip() drops the first n elements and then starts processing.  limit() processes until the count is reached, or the stream ends, whichever comes first.